# Get the string after a pattern in a matrix file and calculate it's length in bash

Tags: shell, matrix, awk

I have the following matrix file :

```
    >ATCSTC     ACD 3.44
   0.39532879396435 0.105513888686126   0.105513888686126 0.393643427745405
   0.00770456803068082  0.00770456803068082 0.00770456803068082 0.976886297348457
   0.976886297348457    0.00770456803068082 0.00770456803068082 0.00770456803068082
```

There are many such files with extension .motif and I want to retrieve the string after ">" and calculate it's length. I tried using all the suggested solutions in here but could not get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '/^>/{print length($1)-1}' file
6
```

Comment: You made String=first word. Maybe OP wants rest of line with $0

Comment: perhaps, but doubt it since there is unformatted white space.